`getLabel` or `fromLabel`
The GHC documentation for OverloadedLabels here shows examples like

Leading capital letters: #Foo equivalant to getLabel @”Foo”

Should getLabel be fromLabel?
AFAIK getLabel is for creating unnamed labels from data constructors in template haskell.
fromLabel is what overloaded labels desugar to.

Looks like a documentation error to me. That text was introduced in c247b6bef, referencing proposal 0170, which only talks about fromLabel, never getLabel.
